# Where is the REST API?

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

After creating a vNext release and trying to initiate it from the command line I quickly realized that it is no longer supported.

In order to figure how to accomplish initiating a release from outside of a TFS build I stumbled upon this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/10/trigger-release-from-build-with-release-management-for-visual-studio-2013-update-3.aspx). However I'm unable to see any REST Api's in my install of release management.

Components Installed:

- Release Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013 with Update 4

#### What I have setup in IIS

Below is where I am expecting to see these API's under something like:

http://RMSERVER:PortNumber/account/releaseManagementService/_apis/releaseManagement/OrchestratorService/

[image: IIS Showing Release Management Site]

**Am I looking in the right spot for this API or do I need to install something else?**

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to see"? Did you try to make a call to the API?

Comment: I don't see the API in IIS. I didn't make any calls because to it because I don't see any sites setup under ReleaseManagement in IIS that follow the pattern I've seen in the post.

Comment: Depending on how they configured routing, you might not see anything under IIS. Follow the instructions in the blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those API's don't physically exist and are provided by a runtime engine. If you use the documented calls you will get access to the API.

Note: Most Rest API's don't physically exist in the way that you describe. You can use Fiddler to interrogate the running API for discoverability.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I ended up doing. Fiddler gave us what we needed to use the API and understand the blog posting better. The only reason I wanted to see where the API existed was to learn how to consume it properly, but as I mentioned then we thought of Fiddler and that solved it for us.

Comment: I wrote an article explaining how to use Fiddler for this and how to translate it to the C# API: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1031429/Programming-against-the-undocumented-Release-Manag

Answer (score 4):

Dan,

We figured out details of Release Management REST API through Release Management Client and Fiddler. After reading many blogs and comments, our team realized that you cannot see API directly. **We learned that after kicking off release from client and watching fiddler**, we can saw see all the **details of the API calls**.

One of the REST API call to initiate release :

```
URL: http://**releaseManagementServer**:**port**/account/releaseManagementService/_apis/releaseManagement/OrchestratorService/InitiateRelease?releaseTemplateName=**releaseTemplateName**&deploymentPropertyBag=**deploymentPropertyBag**&api-version=3.0
Method: POST
```

Parameters of above endpoint:

- releaseManagementServer
- port (default:1000)
- releaseTemplateName
- deploymentPropertyBag

This [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2015/01/14/trigger-visual-studio-release-management-vnext-from-teamcity.aspx) gives you information on creating deploymentPropertyBag parameter.

**PROPERTYBAG**

```
{ 
    "Component1:Build" : "Component1Build_20140814.1",
    "Component2:Build" : "Component2Build_20140815.1",                            
    "ReleaseName" : "$releaseName"
}
```

For Release Management Update4 use api-version=3.0